# Why this loop doesn't work while the similar one works?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function should return True if the list "nums" contains a 3 next to a 3 somewhere.

The function "has_33" should accept a list argument, so this loop works perfectly :-

```py
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0, len(nums)-1):

        if nums[i:i+2] == [3,3]:
            return True  

    return False
```

But when I do it in this form :-

```py
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):  

        if nums[i:i+2] == [3,3]:
            return print("True")
        else:
            if i == len(nums)-1:
                return print("False")
```

> it fails to print "False" if the array doesn't include the condition.

So why the first loop works while the second loop doesn't work although they are the same?

Comment: What is `num` in `num == len(nums)-1`? Also `return print()` does not make much sense. Do you want to print `false/true` or return it?

Comment: looks like the condition is met at the first iteration, then the function returns and no more iterations are performed

Comment: num is the var assigned to every element in list "nums" in the "for" loop

Comment: @AhmedAhmedEG2: Not according to the code you presented here.

Comment: so i said that if the condition didn't met, the first check if num == len(nums)-1 then it can print False becouse this would make sure that the loop fully done it's jop

Comment: Oh iam sorry, i missed something

Comment: You do `for i in range(0,len(nums)-1)` and that means that `i` will never reach the value `len(nums)-1`. The `stop` parameter of `range` is exclusive.

Comment: So I have to make it i == len(nums)-2

Comment: Right. That should work. And of course you should get rid of those `print` calls. Now your function always returns `None` because that's the value returned from a call to `print`.

Comment: Can you make an answer with this comment so i can mark it as solve?

Comment: Someone answered this already. I'm not a point hunter so just accept his answer.

Comment: I did't seen his answer, i accept it as i seen it

Comment: The answer showed up after my comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not put this condition:

```
if i == len(nums)-1:
```

inside your function. And even if you do, use:

```
if i == len(nums)-2:
```

because `i` will never become `len(nums)-1` (see the loop condition above)

Answer (score 1):

`num == len(nums)-1` never evaluates `True`, because num is a list, not an integer.

The bigger issue at hand is though, that this whole else clause is unnecessary, as you can just let python exit the loop, and then print("False"). Additionally,'i suggest the following solution:

```
from itertools import tee


def has_33(nums):
    num1, num2 = tee(nums)
    next(num2)
    for a, b in zip(num1, num2):
        if [a, b] == [3, 3]:
            print("True")
            return
    print("False")
```

Comment: How do you know that `num` is a list?

Comment: OP wrote that the num argument is a list in the first draft of his question, and it is still there as 'the list "nums"'

Comment: I fixed it, i forget that i renamed the var from "num" to "i" so it be more readable, and "nums" is the list and "i" is the var assigned in the loop

Comment: OP just edited his question, and corrected ``if num == len(nums)-1``` with ```if i == len(nums)-1```. OP might consider to keep the original version, otherwise the question becomes unintelligible.